# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.location') [ReactJS + react-router-dom V4]

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm developing a ReactJS app. For my routing setup, I use react-router-dom V4.

My problem is as follows: I'm trying to access "location.pathname" in a file. Nonetheless, I get the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.location')

Sample of side-menu_user-types.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;

//sidebar for each user type
const config = {
  1: {
    desc: [
      <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={[this.props.location.pathname]}>
        <Menu.Item key="/home">
          <NavLink to="/home">
            <Icon type="home"/>
            <span>home</span>
          </NavLink>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    ],
  },
  2: {
    desc: [
      <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={[this.props.location.pathname]}>
        <Menu.Item key="/home">
          <NavLink to="/home">
            <Icon type="home"/>
            <span>home</span>
          </NavLink>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="/nav1">
          <NavLink to="/nav1">
            <Icon type="star-o"/>
            <span>nav 1</span>
          </NavLink>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    ],
  }
};

export default withRouter(config);
```

Sample of side-menu.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const { Sider } = Layout;

class SideMenu extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Sider
        className="sider"
        trigger={null}
        collapsible
        collapsed={this.props.collapsed}
        >
          <div className="logo"/>
          {this.props.sidebar}
        </Sider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = state => ({
  sidebar: state.user.sidebarLoggedIn,
});

export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(SideMenu);
```

PS: I retrieve the sidebar ("this.props.sidebar") in side-menu.js from side-menu_user-types.js, according to the user type (1 or 2), in an action as follows:

- `const sidebar = config[1].desc[0] => user type #1;`
- `const sidebar = config[2].desc[0] => user type #2.`

The const sidebar is then dispatched to my side-menu.js.

Comment: In this expression, `this.props.location.pathname`, `this` has to be under the context of a React Component. Can you provide the sidebar code snippet as well?

Comment: Done! I hope it will help.

Comment: Where is the action getting fired? Can you provide the action and the reducer code as well?

Comment: My action is getting fired in another file (in my login setup). I don't think it is necessary to provide a code snippet of my action/reducer though. I know my problem is in my side-menu_user-types.js file. Somehow I'm not retrieving correctly "location.pathname" from react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference `this.props.location` from config directly as there's no `this` context. (No `props` context as well for that matter).

What you could do is pass the user type from redux store to the `SideMenu` props. Then use this to decide which kind of navbar you want to use.

It could be something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const { Sider } = Layout;

class SideMenu extends React.Component {
  renderSideBar(props) {
      if(props.userType === '1') {
          return (
             <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={[props.location.pathname]}>
                 <Menu.Item key="/home">
                     <NavLink to="/home">
                         <Icon type="home"/>
                         <span>home</span>
                     </NavLink>
                 </Menu.Item>
             </Menu>
          );
      }
      else if(props.userType === '2') {
          return (
              <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={[props.location.pathname]}>
                  <Menu.Item key="/home">
                      <NavLink to="/home">
                          <Icon type="home"/>
                          <span>home</span>
                      </NavLink>
                 </Menu.Item>
                 <Menu.Item key="/nav1">
                    <NavLink to="/nav1">
                        <Icon type="star-o"/>
                        <span>nav 1</span>
                    </NavLink>
                 </Menu.Item>
             </Menu>
          );
      }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Sider
        className="sider"
        trigger={null}
        collapsible
        collapsed={this.props.collapsed}
        >
          <div className="logo"/>
          {this.renderSideBar(this.props)}
        </Sider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = state => ({
  userType: //get user type from state
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStatetoProps)(SideMenu));
```

It only makes sense to store the `userType` in redux-store rather than storing the whole **render layout**.

Comment: Okay, understood! Thank you :)